# Event delegation in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How to get selector string from jQuery plugin initialization, for event delegation use.

Here is simple case:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluginTest = function(){

        $(document).on("click", this, function(e){
            // action here
        });            

    }
}(jQuery));
```

Above code will not work since .on selector type need to be string. So the question is how to get the selector in plugin init.

```
$(".box").pluginTest()
```

How to get `.box` for example. I have been searching this and some suggested to use .selector but now it's deprecated and removed.

Comment: its working fine here ,https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vLg98z8z/1/

Comment: @dreamweiver nope, the click event should be binded to the element, not all document :) i have tried that, and all document returned the click event.

Comment: Why do you care what the selector is, your plugin should not care.  It should only care about the results of the selector the user has chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event handler to the target selector by using `.selector`.

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).on("click",this.selector, function(e) {
  alert('You clicked me!!!');
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vLg98z8z/3/)

In above example you will not get any alert when you click on `.bigBox` & you will get alert only on `.box` since the event handler is bound to the target element by its selector.

Comment: That should work for older version, but it is deprecated and removed https://api.jquery.com/selector/ from the latest version.

Comment: hmmm, i never noticed that. In that case as it is mentioned in jquery api page, why dont you pass the selector also as a parameter when calling the plugin `pluginTest` & use the same to bind the event

Comment: yeah, that should work as mentioned in the docs, but it feel weird when you init the plugin on a selector then pass that selector to plugin param :D

Comment: yeah thats weird alright. i have one dirty workaround ,you can fetch the `class` name(if your sure that class selector is used always) and make it a `class` selector at the plugin side & attach event to that selector. `var cl = '.'+$(this).attr('class');`. I personally dont think the selector being changed at runtime for any `jquery plugin`, in which case this should work.

Answer (score -1):

There are literally hundreds of pages devoted to extending jQuery.  You haven't explain why the following won't work for your plugin:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.pluginTest = function(){
    this.on("click", this, function(e){
        // action here
    }); 
    return this;           
  }
}(jQuery));
```

For example:

```js
      (function($){
      $.fn.pluginTest = function(){
        this.on("click", this, function(e){
            $(this).toggleClass('red');
        }); 
        return this;           
      }
    }(jQuery));

$('.box').pluginTest();
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
.box { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

Comment: I usually use event delegation like this `$(document).on("click", ".box", function(){})` so when there is a DOM change (like added item from ajax) it wouldn't need to re-run the script.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that.  I'm unaware of any plugins that auto-wire up new elements on a page.  Changing that paradigm for just your plugin is problematic.

Comment: Is it the best practice to re call the plugin/function after DOM change? instead of using event delegation. I am open for suggestion :)